# Merging 2 data frames on 3 columns where data sometimes exists

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge

I am attempting merge and fill in missing values in one data frame from another one. Hopefully this isn't too long of an explanation i have just been wracking my brain around this for too long. I am working with 2 huge CSV files so i made a small example here. I have included the entire code at the end in case you were curious to assist. THANK YOU SO MUCH IN ADVANCE. Here we go!

```
print(df1)
   A   B   C   D   E
0  1  B1      D1  E1
1         C1  D1  E1
2  1  B1      D1  E1
3  2  B2      D2  E2
4     B2  C2  D2  E2
5  3          D3  E3
6  3  B3  C3  D3  E3
7  4      C4  D4  E4

print(df2)

   A   B   C   F   G
0  1      C1  F1  G1
1     B2  C2  F2  G2
2  3  B3      F3  G3
3  4  B4  C4  F4  G4
```

I would essentially like to merge df2 into df1 by 3 different columns. i understand that you can merge on multiple column names but it seems to not give me the desired result. I would like to KEEP all data in df1, and fill in the data from df2 so i use how='left'.

I am fairly new to python and have done a lot of research but have hit a stuck point. Here is what i have tried.

```
data3 = df1.merge(df2, how='left', on=['A'])

print(data3)

   A B_x C_x   D   E  B_y  C_y    F    G
0  1  B1      D1  E1        C1   F1   G1
1         C1  D1  E1   B2   C2   F2   G2
2  1  B1      D1  E1        C1   F1   G1
3  2  B2      D2  E2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
4     B2  C2  D2  E2   B2   C2   F2   G2
5  3          D3  E3   B3        F3   G3
6  3  B3  C3  D3  E3   B3        F3   G3
7  4      C4  D4  E4   B4   C4   F4   G4
```

As you can see here it sort of worked with just A, however since this is a csv file with blank values. the blank values seem to merge together. which i do not want. because df2 was blank in row 2 it filled in the data where it saw blanks, which is not what i want. it should be NaN if it could not find a match.

whenever i start putting additional rows into my "on=['A', 'B'] it does not do anything different. in-fact, A no longer merges.

```
data3 = df1.merge(df2, how='left', on=['A', 'B'])
print(data3)

   A   B C_x   D   E  C_y    F    G
0  1  B1      D1  E1  NaN  NaN  NaN
1         C1  D1  E1  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  1  B1      D1  E1  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  2  B2      D2  E2  NaN  NaN  NaN
4     B2  C2  D2  E2   C2   F2   G2
5  3          D3  E3  NaN  NaN  NaN
6  3  B3  C3  D3  E3        F3   G3
7  4      C4  D4  E4  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Rows A, B, and C are the values i want to correlate and merge on. Using both data frames it should know enough to fill in all the gaps. my ending df should look like:

```
print(desired_output):

   A   B   C   D   E   F   G
0  1  B1  C1  D1  E1  F1  G1
1  1  B1  C1  D1  E1  F1  G1
2  1  B1  C1  D1  E1  F1  G1
3  2  B2  C2  D2  E2  F2  G2
4  2  B2  C2  D2  E2  F2  G2
5  3  B3  C3  D3  E3  F3  G3
6  3  B3  C3  D3  E3  F3  G3
7  4  B4  C4  D4  E4  F4  G4
```

even though A, B, and C have repeating rows i want to keep ALL the data and just fill in the data from df2 where it might fit, even if it is repeat data. i also do not want to have all of the _x and _y the suffix's from merging. i know how to rename but doing 3 different merges and merging those merges starts to get really complicated really fast with repeated rows and suffix's...

long story short, how can i merge both data-frames by A, and then B, and then C? order in which it happens is irrelevant.

Here is a sample of actual data. I have my own data that has additional data and i relate it to this data by certain identifiers. basically by MMSI, Name and IMO. i want to keep duplicates because they aren't actually duplicates, just additional data points for each vessel

```
MMSI         BaseDateTime          LAT        LON       VesselName      IMO CallSign
366940480.0  2017-01-04T11:39:36  52.48730 -174.02316    EARLY DAWN     7821130  WDB7319
366940480.0  2017-01-04T13:51:07  52.41575 -174.60041    EARLY DAWN     7821130  WDB7319
273898000.0  2017-01-06T16:55:33  63.83668 -174.41172  MYS CHUPROVA         NaN     UAEZ
352844000.0  2017-01-31T22:51:31  51.89778 -176.59334         JACHA  8512920    3EFC4
352844000.0  2017-01-31T23:06:31  51.89795 -176.59333         JACHA  8512920    3EFC4
```

Comment: Can you provide an excerpt of the original `.csv`? I think the best approach would be to read in the `.csv`, then fill the blank rows with `nans`, this would preserve the index so that later we can merge using the index to position the rows correctly. In the example you provide at the end of your question `df2` won't merge in the way you'd like it to because row 3 (containing B4 etc.) should have the index 7. You can use `df_small = df.iloc[:7,:]` to subset your data, then `df_small.to_clipboard()` to allow you to paste the data into your question.

Comment: Jason! thanks for the reply. unfortunately i cant supply my personal data that i want to append on the end of this data. but i have supplied what would be essentially df1. i added the data to the end of my post as an edit
 What i want is to take MY data, merge it with this by either MMSI, VesselName, IMO, OR Call Sign. (these are identifiers.) i have to use all of those columns because sometimes there is a value supplied and sometimes there isn't. so i want to make sure if one identifier isn't supplied i have three other back up identifiers to merge by. Those 4 columns are the same in df2